# How to integrate a complex function which doesn't have any singularities?

Tags: integration, complex-integration

I am trying to solve this question.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos(z))^{6}dz$$

Usually when I try doing complex integration questions the function has a singularity and you are given a simple closed curve. So I am able to use Cauchy's Residue theorem or Cauchy's integral formula to evaluate the integral. The problem I'm having which this one is that they haven't given a function that has singularities and it isn't a simple closed curve either. I haven't run into this type of problem before and I'm not even sure where to begin. I was wondering whether someone can help on how to go about doing these types of questions. Sorry about not being able to show work I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Whatever it is that you mean by "complex integral", this is not a complex integral.

Comment: See https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnicafolder/ica11.pdf.

Comment: @OpenBall But isn't $f(z) = cos(z)$ a function going from $C$ to $C$?

Comment: But the integration is form $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I'm new to complex integration. I assumed that integrating a function from $C \rightarrow C$ meant it was complex integral. What is the correct definition of being a complex integral?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thanks for the clarification. I understand how to do this question now.

Comment: Let $w = e^{iz}$. Use Euler's formula. You get an integral over the unit circle that you can apply the residue theorem to. In this case, I think just ordinary integration by parts is easier, but the above substitution is the standard way to transform $\int_0^{2\pi} R(\cos t, \sin t)\,dt$ (where $R$ is a rational function) into a form where the residue theorem is applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we can put: $\cos(z)=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$ ,
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2})^{6}dz
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2^6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})^{6}dz
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2^6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}((e^{iz})^6+6(e^{iz})^5e^{-iz}+15(e^{iz})^4(e^{-iz})^2+20(e^{iz})^3(e^{-iz})^3+15(e^{iz})^2(e^{-iz})^4+6(e^{iz})(e^{-iz})^5+(e^{-iz})^6)dz
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2^6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}((e^{iz})^6+6(e^{iz})^4+15(e^{iz})^2+20+15(e^{-iz})^2+6(e^{-iz})^4+(e^{-iz})^6)dz
$$
"Now for first term $\frac{1}{2^6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{iz})^6dz$ , put $t=e^{iz}$ so $dt=i.e^{iz}dz$.

Hence, first term evaluates to (with changed limits)  $\frac{1}{i.2^6}\int_{0}^{1}t^5dt$ , which is equal to $\frac{1}{i.6.2^6}$ ."

**Finally** using this **similar** technique,
$$
\frac{1}{i.6.2^6}+\frac{6}{i.4.2^6}+\frac{15}{i.2.2^6}+\frac{40\pi}{2^6}+\frac{-15}{i.2.2^6}+\frac{-6}{i.4.2^6}+\frac{-1}{i.6.2^6}
$$
$$
\frac{5\pi}{8}
$$
Hence, the final answer is $\frac{5\pi}{8}$ .

Comment: I think you forget to divide by $2^6$, which case the answer is $5\pi/8$. That's the same result as if you just ignored the fact that $z$ is complex and just integrated it as is. As it should be.

Comment: @CyeWaldman thanks i edited my answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Without any specification of an integration *path*, there is no reason to interpret the integral as anything more than it's face value. In other words, just ignore the fact that $z$ is complex. Just as @SahilKumar has shown elsewhere on this page, the integral is simply $5\pi/8$, just as if you integrated $\cos^6(\theta)$.

This is a good time to remind ourselves of the well-known solution for

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta\ d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
n\\
n/2
\end{matrix}
\right)=\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\frac{n!}{(n/2)!^2}
\ \ \ \text{for } n \text{ even}, \text{ and 0 (zero) otherwise}
$$